# PHP to JSON format

Tags: php, json

The JSON format I am getting is:

```
{
    "test":[
        {"key1":"value1"},
        {"key2":"value2"}
     ]
}
```

But is it possible to get this format instead?

```
{
    "test": {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2"
    }
}
```

My php code is this:

```
$key=$row[1];
$value=$row[2];
$posts[] = array($key => $value);

$response['strings'] = $posts;
fwrite($out, json_Encode($response))
```

I've been stuck on this for hours, someone please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
$posts[$key] = $value;
```

The issue is that PHP arrays with string keys are objects in JSON terms.

Answer (score 1):

the first one is an array, the 2nd is an object.

```
$posts = new stdClass();
$posts->key1 = "value1";
$posts->key2 = "value2";

$response['strings'] = $posts;
fwrite($out, json_Encode($response))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your code looks like this:

```
$posts = array();
while( somthing )
{
  $row = ...

  $key=$row[1];
  $value=$row[2];
  $posts[] = array($key => $value);
}

$response['strings'] = $posts;
fwrite($out, json_Encode($response))
```

Your fix is to do this:

```
$posts = array();
while( somthing )
{
  $row = ...

  $key=$row[1];
  $value=$row[2];
  $posts[$key] = $value;
}

$response['strings'] = $posts;
fwrite($out, json_Encode($response))
```